# Google Spreadsheets: copyTo only copies first 20 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy the contents of one sheet into another sheet using the copyTo function but it only seems to copy the first 20 columns.

I want to copy A:AK but only A:T gets copied.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A:AK").copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("A1"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

I can't imagine this is a limit of the copyTo function so not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine Sheet3 is a new sheet you just created. If so, a new sheet will only have columns upto T unless you add them manually. I tried the same code you have and was able to copy all the data after adding the columns manually.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Srik. I'll insert a insertColumns(columnIndex, numColumns) to create the columns I need. Cheers.